# How to Autowire a package private class in integration test without using @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, spring-test

I have a dependency/library in my application. The source code of classes from library is as below.

JwtService.java interface:

```
package com.jwt.accesstoken;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public interface JwtService {
    CompletableFuture<String> jwtToken(String var1);
}
```

JwtServiceImpl.java:

```
package com.jwt.accesstoken;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
class JwtServiceImpl implements JwtService {
      public CompletableFuture<String> jwtToken(String serviceName) {
          //implementation
      }
      ....
```

Integration test (JwtServiceGeneratorTest.kt):

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(JwtService::class)
//@SpringBootTest - this solves compilation error but takes too much time to run test
@ActiveProfiles("it-test")
class JwtServiceGeneratorTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jetService: JwtService //compilation error when using @SpringJUnitConfig
    ....
```

I want to autowire `JwtService.java` in my integration test using `@SpringJUnitConfig`. And `JwtServiceImpl.java` is not public in the dependency.

How can I autowire JwtService.java (which should call `JwtServiceImpl.java` during runtime) in the integration test without using `@SpringBootTest`?

If I do `@SpringJUnitConfig(JwtService::class)` then the integration test complains that there are no beans of type JwtService.java that it can autowire.
I am not able to do `@SpringJUnitConfig(JwtService::class, JwtServiceImpl::class)` because JwtServiceImpl is package-private.

Note: If I use `@SpringBootTest` then the code works but it loads whole application context which is not required for this test and it takes too much time.

Comment: As of now it looks like my only options are using `@SpringBootTest` or create my own implementation copy that does the same thing as JwtServiceImpl.java and autowire/use that in my test class.

Comment: https://github.com/thoqbk/spring-testing/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom configuration class and declare a bean for JwtService. Then you can autowired it anywhere as you like.

```
@Configuration
public class JwtConfiguration(){
  @Bean
  public JwtService jwtService(){
        return new JwtServiceImpl();
   }
}
```

Now import this config anywhere you want and then JwtService is autowired!!

Comment: I cannot do this because JwtServiceImpl is package-private and is part of library. SpringBoot is able to call the JwtServiceImpl at runtime correctly(if I autowire JwtService interface) but I cannot manually create the bean because JwtServiceImpl is not public. only JwtService interface is public.